# How do I change the color of disabledColor on IconButton inside suffixIcon of TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

The problem is that if I change the color of the button in the IconButton's or Icon's color property, the focus color stops working.

```
             TextFormField(
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                         tooltip: 'Show tools',
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
                           onPressed: () {
                         
                          },
                      ),
                   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question.

```
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        iconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
            return Colors.green;
          }
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
            return Colors.red;
          }
          return Colors.green;
        }
        ),
      )
```